# Xcode In-App Purchase TableView Blank

Tags: uitableview, xcode6, in-app-purchase

So I've been following this tutorial on creating In-App Purchases:
http://www.raywenderlich.com/21081/introduction-to-in-app-purchases-in-ios-6-tutorial

I'm stuck on the part where you actually display the in-app purchases in a tableView. I mean first of all he forgot to include the .h file for that view controller... so I have no idea what should be in there. But my problem is that the tableview loads fine but no data appears in it.

```
#import "UpgradeViewController.h"
#import "goIAPHelper.h"
#import <StoreKit/StoreKit.h>

@interface UpgradeViewController () {
    NSArray *_products;
}

@end

@implementation UpgradeViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.title = @"In-App Purchases";
    self.tableView.dataSource = self;
    self.tableView.delegate = self;

    self.refreshControl = [[UIRefreshControl alloc] init];
    [self.refreshControl addTarget:self action:@selector(reload) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
    [self reload];
    [self.refreshControl beginRefreshing];


}

// 4
- (void)reload {
    _products = nil;
    [self.tableView reloadData];
    [[goIAPHelper sharedInstance] requestProductsWithCompletionHandler:^(BOOL success, NSArray *products) {
        if (success) {
            _products = products;
            NSLog(@"Products: %@", _products);
            [self.tableView reloadData];
        }
        else{
            NSLog(@"Not Quite");
        }
        [self.refreshControl endRefreshing];
    }];
}

#pragma mark - Table View

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return 1;
}

// 5
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return _products.count;
    NSLog(@"products count: %d", _products.count);
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    SKProduct * product = (SKProduct *) _products[indexPath.row];
    cell.textLabel.text = product.localizedTitle;
    NSLog(@"Product Title: %@", product.localizedTitle);

    return cell;
}



@end
```

I get a response from the IAPHelper, but I put a lot of NSLogs in the table part of the code and it seems to never even get to that point. Log looks like this:

```
2015-09-10 11:51:37.905 go[1952:1075517] Not purchased: net.hawkinsd.go.noads
2015-09-10 11:51:37.905 go[1952:1075517] Not purchased: net.hawkinsd.go.pebbles
2015-09-10 11:51:39.377 go[1952:1075517] Loaded list of products...
2015-09-10 11:51:39.378 go[1952:1075517] Products: (
)
```

So it basically stops at the "Products" NSLog and doesn't seem to continue any further.

This is my UpgradeViewController.h file:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <StoreKit/StoreKit.h>


@interface UpgradeViewController : UITableViewController <UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource>


@end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright... so anyone who followed that guide (or similar guides) is likely to run into the same problem with the blank table.

Basically the table wasn't populating because iTunes wasn't returning the in-app items... and iTunes wasn't returning the in-app items because you're REQUIRED to have the banking and tax information filled-out.

Furthermore you're also required to have all of that filled out (*and* have already submitted your app) before iAds will work properly.  So those are the conditions for which the table will populate.